# How to transfer all the child objects before deleting the foreignkey object in Django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I am aware that the `on_delete` option can set another foreignkey object as replacement when deleting the existing foreignkey. But what my client want is this flow:

1. Click delete button (from change page or list page in admin)
2. If this object has child elements, show a select box listing all the available foreignkey objects. The selected object will be used to populate the foreignkey of these child objects.
3. Once child objects are transferred to another foreignkey, provide the confirm delete button.

Does anyone have an idea how can I do this on Django admin? Wordpress has this similar functionality when deleting for example a user. It gives the option to transfer the articles to another user.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write your own views to get the flow you describe. It can not be done in Django Admin.

Django Admin is an application on its own, and not really a framework or library you use to create your own applications.

Answer (score 0):

items.models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Slugged(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Item(Slugged):
    # SET_NULL for safety
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Category(Slugged):
    pass
```

items.views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

from jsonview.decorators import json_view
# this is from @jsocol/django-jsonview but there are other ways to do this

from .models import Item, Category


class CategoryUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Category

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.object = super(CategoryUpdateView, self).get_object()
        context = super(CategoryUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['available_fks'] = Category.objects.exclude(pk=self.object.id)      
        context.update(kwargs)
        return super(CategoryUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)


class CategoryDeleteView(generic.DeleteView, FormMixin):
    model = Task
    success_url = '/'

    @json_view
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CategoryDeleteView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = super(CategoryDeleteView, self).get_object()
        self.object.delete()
        return {'success':True}

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = super(CategoryDeleteView, self).get_object()
        if request.POST.has_key('new_fk'):
            new_fk = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=request.POST['new_fk'])
            for item in self.object.item_set.all():
                item.category = new_fk
                item.save()
        else:
            return {'success': False}
        return self.delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

items.templates.items.category_update.html

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="category-delete-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <select id="new_fk">
        <option value="" >---------</option>
        {% for fk in available_fks %} 
             <option value="{{ fk.if }}"{% if forloop.first %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ fk.title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="delete_category" value="Delete">
</form>
```

items.static.items.deleteItem.js

```
function deleteCategory(deleteUrl, form_id) {
    var $form = $('#' + form_id);
    var new_pk = $form.find('#new_fk').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: deleteUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'csrfmiddlewaretoken=' + getCookie('csrftoken') + '&new_fk=' + new_fk,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['success']){
                $form.remove();
                alert('success');
            }
            else {
                alert('FAIL');
            }

        }
    });
}
$('#category-delete-form').on('submit', function () {
    $this = $(this);
    deleteCategory($this.attr('action'), $this.id);
}
```

[@goldhand gist](https://gist.github.com/goldhand/6339278)